# ComboBox not updating when object added to bound list

Tags: c#, winforms, bindinglist

I have an object that represents a client, and that object has a list of the clients branches:

```
private List<Branch> _branches;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Branches"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem(typeof(Branch))]
public List<Branch> Branches
{
    get { return _branches; }
    set
    {
        _branches = value;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Branches"));
        }
    }
}
```

In one form (WinForms) I have a ComboBox that I've bound to that list:

```
// creating a binding list for the branches
var bindingList = new BindingList<Branch>(Client.Branches);

// bind list to combo box
cmbBranches.DataSource = bindingList;
cmbBranches.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbBranches.ValueMember = "Name";
```

In another function, I create a new `Branch` object and add it to the existing list: `Client.Branches.Add(newBranch)`.  I would expect this to update the ComboBox but it doesn't.  Why not, and how do I make it update?  (Edit: I'd also like this to update when removing an object from the list. The reason it doesn't work is, I assume, directly related to why the box isn't updating when `Add` is called.)

In doing research, I found this SO answer, which seems to imply that it will work.  I feel like I'm missing something simple ...

[difference between ObservableCollection and BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist/4284805#4284805)

**Edit:** Some further information about what I've tried and some additional goals.

I cannot use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` as I need to use `Exists` in the code. Which the former doesn't have.

I need to update the original list when the new object is added, in addition to updating the drop down box.

To summarize my comments below, I attempted adding this:

```
var bindingList = (BindingList<Branch>) cmbBranches.DataSource;
bindingList.Add(frmAddBranch.NewBranch);
```

But that results in the object being added to the ComboBox twice.  Somehow by calling `bindingList.Add` it's "resetting" the data source and doubling up.  I cannot find any function that "refreshes" the data display once it's bound.  `Control.ResetBindings()` did not work.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575397/cant-figure-out-how-to-convert-class-strings-to-a-datagrid/13575912#13575912

Comment: Wait, so I need to then add the member to `bindingList`? That makes sense ...

Comment: @MPatel - I added this code, and now the new object shows up in the ComboList twice!  `var bindingList = (BindingList<Branch>) cmbBranches.DataSource;
                    bindingList.Add(frmAddBranch.NewBranch);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work that way. The inner `List<T>` has no change notification mechanism, so adding directly to inner `List<T>` will not generate any change notification that would eventually reach the combo box. Most convenient way to do what you want is adding the item through the `BindingList<T>` instead.

Comment: Please see my last comment to MPatel above ... that results in the object being added twice to the ComboBox.

Comment: Did you forget to remove your old `Client.Branches.Add(newBranch)`?

Comment: If you have to add to the underlying `List<T>`, you can call `BindingList<T>.ResetBindings` afterward to force update.

Comment: calling `BindingList<T>.ResetBindings()` was the trick.  I was trying to call `ResetBindings()` on the ComboBox, not the binding list.  Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the items directly to the `BindingList` (but not to the backing `Branches` list - the `BindingList` should take care of this for you).